# Vimeo /me/projects pagination

Tags: vimeo

I have 26 folders on vimeo, and I want to look for a specific folder with the REST API.
But when I call /me/projects, i get a result like this:

```
"total": 26,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 25,
"paging": {
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "first":"/me/projects?page=1",
  "last": "/me/projects?page=1"
}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: What's the problem? What's the response you are expecting?